# NUI with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Has anyone got `NUI` working with `Swift` and `CocoaPods`?

`NUI` is a drop-in UI kit for `iOS` that lets you style UI elements using a stylesheet, similar to `CSS`. It lets you style an entire app in minutes.

[NUI LINK](https://github.com/tombenner/nui)

If I include this in my Bridging Header :

```
#import <NUI/NUISettings.h>
```

I'm getting this error `Could not build module NUI`

I added "`use_framework`!" in my `PodFile`.

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Check the GitHub Issues page for the NUI project: https://github.com/tombenner/nui/issues/291

Comment: Thx but I have already checked this page. dfoerderreuther don't really help me and he forgot the essential add `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile. Moreover, other members have continued to add comments in the issue... I can use NUI in my Objc files but It's impossible in Swift files.

Comment: Check the changes made by 'timbodeit' in this commit:
[#307](https://github.com/tombenner/nui/pull/307/commits/b3691c4f157cc6c2921b119d07162af9e70e6dd7)

When using the new `use_frameworks!` option in Cocoapods, by default errors about non-module imports are thrown, whenever a header is imported with "" that does not belong to the same module (same target)

To circumvent this, import dependencies using </> when possible

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a common issue not specific with NUI, I used faced with some other framework with could find/build xxx.

And solved with deleting past pod relevent files (.lock \Pods xcworkspace) and reinstall with

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2303/)

1. I've closed xcode
2. Ran 'pod install''
3. Open xcode
4. Build succeeded.

Please make sure you bridging header is working properly as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this fork instead: https://github.com/peantunes/nui
At least as long as v0.6.0 isn't released which might fix this problem.

```
  pod 'NUI',:git => 'https://github.com/peantunes/nui.git'
```

Comment: Can also refer to this commit which has been merged but not part of the pod:
[#307](https://github.com/tombenner/nui/pull/307/commits/b3691c4f157cc6c2921b119d07162af9e70e6dd7)

Answer (score -1):

For me only one thing fixed. Changed in Podfile:

from: `pod 'NUI'`

to: `pod 'NUI', :head`